# MAMP Pro (Windows): Cannot launch on system startup

Tags: windows, wamp, mamp, mamp-pro

**I've got MAMP Pro 4 installed on my *Windows machine*.**

Everything works correct, but I cannot enable the automatic start when the OS launches.

In fact, the checkbox "Start Groupstart Servers on System Startup" in the Ports page is disabled and I cannot check it.

*So, the question is, how can I enable that option?*

---

> Since I haven't find any solution searching on the web, I've decided
>   to ask here. MAMP is not very diffused on Windows, it would be good to
>   spread some informations, I like it as I used it on my old Mac (the
>   only thing that I don't like is the amount of languages installed:
>   ruby, perl, etc.. Maybe with a custom install one can avoid to install
>   them, but I missed that this time).

Comment: You should uncheck option "Start Groupstart Servers when opening MAMP PRO". Then you can select  "Start Groupstart Servers on System Startup". Save and restart servers. Restart machine. (it is better for PHP to work in Module Handler mode)

Comment: thank man! I've solved in the meanwhile... By going back to xampp :-)